# ResultSet returns blank column in CSV

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, opencsv

I'm using [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) and Postgres.
In Postgres I have a column **gender**:

```
 'gender' AS gender,
```

(the table itself is a view and the gender column is a placeholder for a value that gets calculated in Java)

In Java when I .fetch() the view, I do some calculations on each record:

```
     for (Record r : skillRecords) {
            idNumber=function(r)
            r.set(id, idNumber);
            r.set(gender,getGender(idNumber));
        }
```

All looks good and if println the values they're all correct.
However, when I call intoResultSet() on my skillsRecord, the gender column has an asterisks next to all the values, eg "*Male".

Then, I use the resultset as input into an OpenCSV CSV writer and when I open the CSV the gender column comes out as null.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Following the input from Lukas regarding the asterisks, I realise the issue is likely with opencsv.

My code is as follows:

```
        File tempFile = new File("/tmp/file.csv");

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(out);
        //Code for getting records sits here
     for (Record r : skillRecords) {
        idNumber=function(r)
        r.set(id, idNumber);
        r.set(gender,getGender(idNumber));
    }
        writer.writeAll(skillRecords.intoResultSet(), true);
        return tempFile;
```

All the columsn in the CSV come back as expected, except the gender column, which has the header "gender" but the column values are empty.
I have the necessary try/catches in the code above but I've excluded them for brevity.

Comment: I've answered the part that corresponds to `"*Male"`. Would you mind adding a bit more information about the `null` part in OpenCSV?

Answer (score 1):

#### The asterisk in *Male

The asterisk that you see in the `ResultSet.toString()` output (or in `Result.toString()`) reflects the record's internal [`Record.changed(Field)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#changed-org.jooq.Field-) flag, i.e. the information on each record that says that the record was modified *after* it was retrieved form the database (which you did).

That is just visual information which you can safely ignore.

Comment: Ahh many thanks for explaining that! Updated my answer with more info

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

So I found the solution. It turns out with postgres if I have something like:

```
'gender' AS gender,
```

The type is **unknown**, not **text**. So the solution was to define as:

'gender'::text AS gender

After doing so OpenCSV was happy.